# Tkinter PopUp window not taking the textvariable values from Entry and Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I used Tkinter in Python3 to create a GUI and one of the functions is a pop up window after a button click. This is how my popup window looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKFVC.png). The pop up window will take the user inputs and update a variable from the class object (self). Everything works fine except the part in the function **UpdateValues()** as shown in the code below.

After inputting and updating the **Frequency** (variable freq in the code) and **Iterations** (variable **loop** in code) values in the popup window, they fail to print on the terminal and give a blank screen. Thus the **self.freq** and **self.loop** are unable to get updated.

I'm a newbie to python-classes and tkinter and have been struggling with this problem for a while now. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

**CODE:**

```
'''Class and other attributes here'''    

# Blinking light ssh command
    self.freq = "500"
    self.loop = "10"
    def RunCode():
        cmd = "sshpass -p \"raspberry\" ssh -to StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@pi ./led "+self.freq+" "+self.loop
        os.system(cmd)

    def PopUpBox1():
        popup = tk.Tk()
        popup.title("Edit Parameters")
        w = 325
        h = 75
        x = (ws/2) - w/2
        y = (hs/2) - h/2
        popup.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y))
        popup.resizable(False,False)

        # Adding widgets to PopUpBox
        # Modified Button Click Function for Update
        def UpdateValues(): 
            update.configure(text='Updated')
            print(freq.get())
            print(loop.get())
            self.freq = str(freq.get())
            self.loop = str(loop.get())
            popup.destroy()

        # Frequency and Iterations label
        ttk.Label(popup, text="Frequency:",font='200').grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(popup, text="Iterations:",font='200').grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='w')

        # Adding a Textbox Entry widget for frequency values
        freq = tk.StringVar()
        name_entered = tk.Entry(popup, width=12, textvariable=freq)
        name_entered.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Adding a Combobox for iteration values
        loop = tk.StringVar()
        number_chosen = ttk.Combobox(popup, width=12, textvariable=loop)
        number_chosen['values'] = (1, 2, 4, 42, 100)
        number_chosen.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        number_chosen.current(0)

        # Adding a Button for Updation
        update = ttk.Button(popup, text="Update", command = UpdateValues)
        update.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Place cursor into name Entry
        name_entered.focus()
```

Comment: Do you have `tk.Tk()` in more than one place in your code? Please show us a [mcve]. the code you posted isn't complete.

Comment: You can't use two instances of `tk`. You need to call `tk.Tk()` exactly once. If you need additional windows, you need to use `Toplevel`. Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a proper [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. Thank you!